# Not able to align text for Radiobuttonlist in Arabic

Tags: css, asp.net, arabic, right-to-left, radiobuttonlist

I am not able to align the DisplayText for the Radiobuttonlist.

```
   <asp:Label ID="Q1_Lbl" runat="server" Text="<%$ Resources:Question, Q1_Lbl%>" ForeColor="Black" Font-Size="18px"></asp:Label>
                                                <div dir="rtl">
                                                    <asp:RadioButtonList ID="Q1_Radio" runat="server" Font-Size="18px" CssClass="radio-inline" RepeatDirection="Vertical">
                                                        <asp:ListItem Text="<%$ Resources:Answer, Yes_Lbl%>" Value="50"></asp:ListItem>
                                                        <asp:ListItem Text="<%$ Resources:Answer, No_Lbl%>" Value="0"></asp:ListItem>
                                                    </asp:RadioButtonList>
                                                </div>
```

I am getting this.
[image]

```
 <style>
        .rtl{direction:rtl;text-align:right;}
.ltr{direction:ltr;text-align:left;}
    </style>
```

Please help me align the text correctly.

Comment: Please replace the code with html markup (as on the result-page) and include text we can use (not code); any language. Have you tried any css? Include what you have tried.

Comment: In your style, you target something with `class="rtl"`, but there's nothing like that in the source, only `dir="rtl"`.

Comment: please check again.. i updated it